# how to disable CET and shadow stack in gcc

Tags: gcc, callstack

I am teaching OS and I need to explain the functioning of the stack and the function call convention in C by using real disassembled code of a simple C function.
For didactic purpouses, in a first phase I prefer to avoid explaing all the security features of modern processor architectures. So I would like to compile my simple example without the stack shadowing feature (it is already difficult to explain how the stack works, imagine doing it with 2 stacks!). However, I have no idea of how to disable it in gcc. I am using gcc 9.3.0 on Ubuntu, I enable the following flags:

```
CFLAGS32 = -g -c -m32 -z execstack
```

Any clue ?fl

Comment: Prehaps `-mno-shstk`

Comment: additionally consider `-fcf-protection=none` and `-fno-stack-protector`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @PeterT, the `-fcf-protection=none` did the trick! `-mno-shstk` for some reason had no effect on my code.